# Are every scheme's structure sheaf's restrictions to $U$ from the global sections given by localizing by functions nonvanishing on $U$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes, localization

Another question to add to the above is, also for local stalks?

In detail:

For affine schemes $X = \operatorname{Spec}(R)$ with structure sheaf $\mathcal{O}$ we have the following general facts:

- for open $U\subseteq X$,
  we have that the ring $\mathcal{O}(U)$ is identified with (in a way extending to a sheaf isomorphism)
  $\Gamma_{\text{global}}(\mathcal{O}) = R$ localized by (the multiplicative set of) all $f \in R$ which are nowhere-vanishing in $U$.
- for a point $x\in X$, the local stalk $\mathcal{O}_x$ is identified with
  $R$ localized by (the multiplicative set of) all $f \in R$ which are non-vanishing at $x$.

My questions are:

1. Do these also hold for general schemes $(X,\mathcal{O})$, with $R$ replaced by $\Gamma_{\text{global}}(\mathcal{O})$?
2. If the answer to 1 is yes: does it also hold for locally ringed spaces in general?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. For example, $X = \mathbb P^1_{k}$, and take $U = \mathbb A^1_k\subset X$ which has $\Gamma(U, O_X|_U) = k[x]$ so that the stalks at any point of $U$ (or $X$ for that matter) will be way larger than $k$ so could not possibly be a localization of the global sections.

Comment: Great, thank you!

Comment: Could I ask: does the result I stated hold for affine varieties? (If I'm not mistaken, the projective line cannot be realized as an affine variety?)

Comment: What do you think? You should know what each closed set in an affine scheme looks like (and thus the open sets). See if you can work it out.

Comment: Actually, haven't you already addressed this in your question itself?

Comment: When I said "affine variety" I was thinking of a closed subscheme of the affine n-plane over a field, which is a case I didn't consider in my question. (Unless I'm mistaken, closed subschemes of the affine n-plane need not be affine themselves.)

Comment: @IndraneelTambe2 Closed subschemes of affine schemes are affine!